# How Do I monitor connection pool programmatically in Jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, connection-pooling, jmx, wildfly-9

I am working on project where there is a need to monitor connection pool usage like ActiveCount, AvailableCount, MaxUsedCount. I am struggling to find something useful. I know that connection pool craetes an MBean and binds it with the underlying available JMX server.This MBean will hold all the information about the connection pool. I want have access to this MBean so that I can access all attributes inside it.

However I know if I execute jboss-cli.sh in linux environment and execute

`/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS/statistics=pool:read-resource(include-runtime=true)`

I will get below output

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "ActiveCount" => "0",
        "AvailableCount" => "20",
        "AverageBlockingTime" => "0",
        "AverageCreationTime" => "0",
        "CreatedCount" => "0",
        "DestroyedCount" => "0",
        "MaxCreationTime" => "0",
        "MaxUsedCount" => "0",
        "MaxWaitTime" => "0",
        "TimedOut" => "0",
        "TotalBlockingTime" => "0",
        "TotalCreationTime" => "0"
    }
}
```

Now same thing I wanted to achieve using programmatically. I am not sure how do I do this. Because I will run some program which will run at specific time interval and log connection data like ActiveCount, AvailableCount, MaxUsedCount which can be used further.

NOTE: I am using wilfly-9.0.1.Final

Please Guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CLI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes) to get these statistics. To do so execute it from code as [terminal command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468715/executing-terminal-commands-from-java) and parse result.

Also there is [The HTTP management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+HTTP+management+API) and [The native management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+native+management+API)

Comment: Thanks for you response. Is there any way through which I can log connection pool count ?

Comment: Look for JCA (Java EE Connector Architecture) logging here http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1050 , though it is debug level.

Comment: I tried this but could not find anything in the log.

Comment: Set root-logger level to TRACE too.

Comment: It is logging now. But every time I get ActiveCount, AvailableCount as zero even if 2 is in use and max size is 30. So I suppose if in use count is 2 and max size is 30 I should see ActiveCount 3 and AvailableCount 27. But I am seeing all zero. What is wrong now ?

Comment: Check pool name in the log. Is it the pool you are looking for? If so, compare stats with web console stats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113010/discussion-between-mahendra-kawde-and-doge).